# Reactjs Router Can't GET /page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am facing an awkward issue with reactjs. it is about routing. When route to any page, it really works great ! only problem, when i reload a page, it fires this `Cannot GET /employee`  here employee is my page name!

I am not getting why i am seeing this.

this is my index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from "../client/components/App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import postReducer from '../client/postReducer'

const store = createStore(postReducer)


// if we don't subcribe, yet our crud operation will work
function onStateChange() {
  const state = store.getState();
}

store.subscribe(onStateChange)

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

and this is my `app.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../components/home';
import Contacts from '../components/contact';
import About from '../components/about';
import Employees from '../components/Employees';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> Home </Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/employee'} className="nav-link">Employee</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/contact'} className="nav-link">Contact</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/about'} className="nav-link">About</Link></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          <hr />
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route path='/employee' component={Employees} />
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contacts} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is my `webpack`

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
});
```

Can anyone please help me to to fix this error `Cannot GET /employee` ?

Comment: Is it only on production or also on development ? Sounds like your webserver is not configure to redirect 404 to index.html, classic, but should not happen on dev.

Comment: In production, it show another way, also that is error too

Comment: you most likely need to configure your .htaccess file in production to handle react router. check this link https://gist.github.com/joellongie/e6f4a3b5fa98c521782619e487aca15a

Comment: My Backend is django

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate with the following : [react routing and django url conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826295/react-routing-and-django-url-conflict?noredirect=1)

> The issue is probably that you haven't configured your URLs to handle
>   the routes that are defined in React Router. In your Django urls.py
>   you should be using a catch all to match all URLs to your index
>   template
>
> ```
> urlpatterns += [
>     # match the root
>     url(r'^$', base_view),
>     # match all other pages
>     url(r'^(?:.*)/?$', base_view),
> ]
> ```
>
> The base_view would be a view function that renders a template which
>   includes your bundled app.

However, **you should not serve static files using django**, it has not been designed for it and will perform not greatly . One quick option is to integrate django [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html), but best practice is to use a web server like nginx, or even better a cdn. You can host for free your static files like react bundle app on [github pages](https://pages.github.com/), which is also nice.