# How can I get django to redirect all unknown urls to `/`

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

How can I get django to redirect all unknown urls to `/`

Since the react part of the project uses react-router, it changes the url in the SPA.  So if I go to `/options` in the app, it works, but if I were to enter the url and cold load from `http://example.com/options`, uwsgi returns a 404.

What is the proper thing to do to prevent this?

Comment: static files cannot be served by whitenoise unless they are in the static directory defined by `STATIC_ROOT` (where they will all end up after you run `manage.py collectstatic`). And `collectstatic` finds all static files in each app's `static` directory + the directories you add to `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: So the only way to serve top-level files like */favicon.ico* or */manifest.json* is to add them explicitly to your webserver's configuration (nginx).

Comment: Redirecting unknowns urls to the root one is actually a bad idea - you should just setup a proper 404 page.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ok so I'll explicitly only redirect if it matches a pattern used in react-router by adding those urls to my `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question,use [**`404 handler`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404)

```
# root_dir/views.py
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect


def handler404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


# root_dir/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...,
    ...,
]
handler404 = 'root_dir.views.handler404'
```

Comment: This does make it redirect, but it loses the rest of the URL.  Is there a way to make it redirect but keep the url so that react will handle it?

Comment: @cclloyd then in your handler, just add the url (`request.path`).

Comment: You are right.  To be more specific I followed the instructions here, adding it to the end of my urlpatterns (if I add it before other routes, it chooses that instead) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826672/2228592