# Django/React App: How to have both Django URLS (for the api to send data) and React URLS (to render my components) in my web app, compatibly

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, url

I just added this to the urls.py in my react folder: `re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', views.index),` after following this stackoverflow post: [react routing and django url conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826295/react-routing-and-django-url-conflict). My error in the dev tools is: Unknown_URL_Scheme

**However,** in my situation, this creates problems. My method of sending JSONs to my react is through the url: `"api/leads,"` which is now inaccessible. How do I produce a way for my react urls to exist in harmony with my django urls? Attached are my `django urls.py, react--> App.js, urls.py, views.py, index.html, and DataFetching.py` (where you will be able to see how I send the data from my api).

**Django: urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/lead/', views.LeadListCreate.as_view()),

]
```

**Django Project: urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    
]
```

**React--> urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index),
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', views.index),
]
```

By the way, I tried to look at the documentation for urls(r^...) and it wouldn't tell me how to import it, but instead basically said that urls is basically the same as re_path; this may be the problem, nonetheless, I would still not know the solution.

**React-->views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

**React--> App.js**

```
import './index.css';
import BellIcon from './icons/bell.svg';
import MessengerIcon from './icons/messenger.svg';
import CaretIcon from './icons/caret.svg';
import PlusIcon from './icons/plus.svg';
import DataFetching from "../DataFetching";
import DropdownMenu from "../DropDown";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar>
        <NavItem icon={<PlusIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<BellIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<MessengerIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<CaretIcon />}>
          <h1> Hello World </h1>
          <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
        </NavItem>
      </Navbar>
      
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
            <DataFetching />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

(There is more, but it is not relevant)

**DataFetching.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DataFetching() {
    const [leads, setLeads] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("api/lead")
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res)
                setLeads(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    leads.map(lead => <li key={lead.id}>{lead.name} says {lead.message}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataFetching
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
      <!-- React will load here -->
  </div>
  {% load static %}
  <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you have a better way to send data to my react app, or other useful insights, feel free to drop in the chat!

EDIT PROGRESS: NONE, STILL HAVE NO CLUE ABOUT WHERE TO EVEN START ON THIS PROBLEM, CAN'T FIND ANYTHING OF SUSBSTANCE ON THE TOPIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my thoughts about your problem:

**First,** you don't have any urls at path `api/leads/` but you do have `api/lead/` defined in urls.py. It might be a typo. Also at axios, you should use `axios.get("/api/lead/")`.

**Second,** your urls should be in harmony. Because of the order of urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('leads.urls')), 
    path('', include('frontend.urls')), 
    
]
```

If you hit the django server at path `/`, first it tries with first path, as it does not match at `/admin`, it goes to second path. It does not match either, so finally it matches with regex `^(?:.*)/?$`(any path should match that) at third path, hence React app should be visible there. So it should work if you fix the typo.

**Third,** it would be best to have React application served differently then using Django. You can use Nginx to serve the React application seperatly in production. Or there are [documentations](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) on how you can serve React in production. In local machine, you can use `npm start` or `yarn start` to run the application. Then there will come the issue for authenitcation and session in React. You can use [Token based authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) to resolve that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, it did not solve the issue of the urls. Gave the +50 because it was well thought out and useful in other way.

Comment: @AndrewBregman thats unfortunate. Can you please share the exact error with full error stack trace? Can you please verify the API urls are working or not? Check from browser if the axios is calling the right api? Finally, try commenting out the frontend url, and see if you can access the leads url?

Comment: Hi Ruddra. There is no error message because it is just the react routes taking precendence over the API urls, so if I type in my api url, the react api will render, instead of the api. The API urls are indeed working, I tested this out by removing all the react stuff. Axios cannot call from the api because the link it goes to fetch from is a link that renders the react components instead of JSON files in the API view. If I comment out frontend url, I CAN acess the leads URL.

Comment: Well, axios should not get the react routing in response as when it hits the url, it should go through Django first. You can try to run another server in Django, and see axios is hitting that (if you get CORS error, ensure to handle that). Also can you please try with this url for react: `re_path(r'^.*$', views.index),` as well?

Comment: yes axios is hitting that. I tried the re_path with regex and that did not work either.

Answer (score 4):

I added the following re_path at the end of the project urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    re_path(r'.*', views.home)
]
```

that will make all the other previous django url paths work, and if a not existent path is requested should be handled by react router.

the source of my approach
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830788/11335825)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed the issue:

Django project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),

]
```

Urls for django app (API)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('lead/', views.LeadListCreate.as_view()),
    path('profiles/', views.ProfileAPI.as_view()),

]
```

Urls for frontend

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index),
    url('', views.index)
]
```

Comment: Hi Andrew,
i am just confronted with the very same issue (React frontend, Django Rest backend, Axios). I'm very glad that I came across your posts here :). Thank you very much!!!
I'm trying to recreate your solution, changing my own project accordingly to troubleshoot more successfully. Therefore, could you tell me what kind of `views` `LeadListCreate` and `ProfileAPI` are?

Comment: Hi @Schelmuffsky. My LeadListCreate and ProfileAPI are Django REST Framework built APIs. So they basically look like ```class ProfileAPI(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['id']....``` Then, you'll have to create Serializer models that define the data you want to pass to your API. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: thank you! cool. I'm going to try it using `APIViews`, then.

Comment: Let me know if you run into difficulties @Schelmuffsky