# "Any" path in Django?

Tags: reactjs, django

Is it possible to define a route that will be redirected to if Django could not find a match in the defined URLs?

For example, let's say I have:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ajaxlogin', views.ajax_login, name='ajaxlogin'),
    path('ajaxprofile', views.ajax_profile, name='ajaxprofile'),
]
```

Can I define a "dynamic" URL of a specific view that will be redirected to if the path doesn't exist? Suppose I enter the URLs `/ajaxsignup` and `/ajaxdelete`, which are not defined, but have them redirected to a URL of a certain view?

In other words:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ajaxlogin', views.ajax_login, name='ajaxlogin'),
    path('ajaxprofile', views.ajax_profile, name='ajaxprofile'),
    path('every-other-url', views.another_view, name='path-everything-else'),
]
```

I know there's Django's error handlers, but are there any other ways to achieve this? I have my frontend based separately on a React application, so I'd very much appreciate a "dynamic" URL rather than using Django's default 404 responses.

I suspect that if `path` couldn't do it, I could use the old `url` with regex -- but I still have no clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't re_path work with a wildcard at the end of your urlpatterns list?

Comment: @Trent can you please elaborate (or probably post a documentation link or something)?

Comment: Yeah I found the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#re-path), but can you please tell me how to exclude the two defined URLs above? Or will `re_path` handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a wildcard re_path at the end of your urlpatterns:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import re_path

def http_response(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello HttpResponse</h1>')

urlpatterns = [
    path('ajaxlogin', views.ajax_login, name='ajaxlogin'),
    path('ajaxprofile', views.ajax_profile, name='ajaxprofile'),
    path('every-other-url', views.another_view, name='path-everything-else'),
    re_path(r'.*', http_response), # only if the above routes don't trigger a match
]
```

It processes routes in order, so if it doesn't find a route before it hits the wildcard, it will return that one.

Comment: Can I replace `http_response` with a particular view?

Comment: You can do whatever you want there. I just wanted to give you a working example that you could plug into your django urls.py and test.